# Show Processlist state "Statistics"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

Please note that it's not a duplicate thread because I already set variable `optimizer_search_depth` and didn't have any impact.

Sometimes, our database/application services crashed due to max connection limit. When we see `show processlist` output we found lot of sessions in the "statistics" state. Our system immediately get normal if we kill these connections. We are not running any DDL/optimize/stats-update related commands during that period. We are using 5.7.12 on Linux Centos 7.5

How can I find the source of these sessions?

Comment: Please post your 'connect', process, CLOSE() logic.  If 'Killing' a PID frees your system, someone missed a necessary CLOSE to release resources.  There could be other reasons as well.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where we have FREE downloadable Utility Scripts, other services and contact information.

Comment: Set `long_query_time` low; turn on the slowlog; wait a while; use pt-query-digest to summarize the slowlog.  Then, let's see the worst query, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: If you have an EAV schema, then it _may_ be a dup of those `optimizer_search_depth` postings.

Comment: It would also be helpful to post the complete last 400 lines of your error log after a failure AND your complete TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; before you Kill a process.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Our error log file is too big and I have scanned the whole file and didn't find specific issue. 
RickJames My slow queries time already set 5 sec and didn't find any specific command.

Comment: @lrfi Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where you will find FREE downloadable Utility Scripts, other services and contact info for assistance.  We only need the last 400 line from your error log (copy and paste to a short log file) for an idea of recent errors.  TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; posted would be helpful to research your troubles.

Answer (score 1):

This can be related to [Bug 83912](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83912). If you run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` you may see transactions like this:

> ---TRANSACTION 4216198446592, not started sleeping before entering InnoDB

In order to fix it:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_thread_concurrency=0;
```